# Ошибка при сохранении данных даты и времени в БД

Tags: c#

При сохранении данных происходит ошибка

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 
An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
SqlException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

В строке

```cs
_testContext.SaveChanges();
```

Мне кажется проблема возникла из за миграции данных в БД атрибуты: `DateOfBirth date`, `CreatedDateTime datetime`, `WakeUpTime time(7)`.  При миграции эти атрибуты имели один тип `datetime2`:

```cs
DateOfBirth = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
CreatedDateTime = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
WakeUpTime = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
```

Я пробовал изменить с datetime2 на параметры которые установлены в БД. Не помогает.

Comment: Ну вы посмотрите, что там за даты, на которых ошибка выходит. Может там где-то `NULL` у вас? Ну и тут почитайте https://stackoverflow.com/a/4284996/8324991

Comment: Что было до миграции и что стало после? EF какой версии? Какая РСУБД используется?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён, проблема была в миграции данных, явно указал данные через атрибуты в модели.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/885891)

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].

Comment: @чистов_n это как раз ответ, только очень сжатый. Это не правка к вопросу.